# ExecutorService and accepting new task after shutdown when waiting for other task to finish

Tags: java, android, multithreading, executorservice

Please suggest a solution for android application where user can request to perform a task by click on a button.

*Here task is non ui activity

- I need to allow user to perform multiple request
- During multiple task execution task excutor should wait to finish all the task.
- When any task is finished out of multiple task and task executor is waiting for other task to finish then if user request for other 
  task so I should be accepted and performed.
- This task should happen in the android service so on exit of the application it should not terminate.

How I am performing :

- I am performing tasks using ExcutorService &
  ExecutorCompletionService it throws error because task executor is
  waiting for other task to finish then if user request for other  task

java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task java.util.concurrent.ExecutorCompletionService$QueueingFuture@4198abe8 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@41caf8f8[Shutting down, pool size = 1, active threads = 1, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 1]

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (mIsAlreadyRunning) {
            MyTask task = new MyTask(++count, intent);
            mEcs.submit(task);
        }
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        if (mIsAlreadyRunning) {
            return;
        }
        mIsAlreadyRunning = true;
        final Collection<MyTask> tasks = mTasks;

        MyTask yt1 = new MyTask(count, intent);
        tasks.add(yt1);

        // wait for finish
        for (MyTask t : tasks) {
             mEcs.submit(t);
        }

        int n = tasks.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            NoResultType r;
            try {
                r = mEcs.take().get();

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        mExec.shutdown();

        try {
            mExec.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using IntentService correctly. It's giving the error because you're submitting another task while the executor has shutdown() called on it.

Docs for IntentService:

> All requests are handled on a single worker thread -- they may take as
>   long as necessary (and will not block the application's main loop),
>   but only one request will be processed at a time.

About onStartCommand() for IntentService:

> You should not override this method for your IntentService.

You should restructure everything and use a regular Service, with tasks being submitted in onStartCommand(), and calling exec.shutdown() in onDestroy().

Comment: I need to allow user to perform multiple request(task) simultaneously so this solution I guess will not server the purpose. Please suggest .

Comment: A regular Service will allow multiple requests simultaneously. You submit the request to the executor in onStartCommand(). IntentService is the wrong way to go, it is meant for serial requests.

Comment: Thanks.This works fine with multiple tasks, But service is not stopping. its keep on running and destroy is not called as doing as you suggested.It should shutdown one task is complete. I need to broadcast something on destroy. please suggest.

Comment: What harm is it if the Service keeps running? The tasks run to completion and it does nothing, awaiting the next task until destroyed by the system.

Comment: I'm sure there's a way to rig it up to stopself() the service, but why? Android will clean it up when it needs to.

Comment: Actually I need to broadcast the progress of task to activity where I am showing a progress bar.Once task is done I need to remove it from the pool and need not to show progress in activity.  So Now I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: You could have the tasks send a callback when they complete.

Comment: Could you please share a link or code how to do this ?

Comment: You're actually asking for a tall order. You don't want to hold a reference to an Activity anywhere in the Service since you said it could live longer than the Activity (which will you need to update a progress bar). The proper way of doing it without a bunch of coding would be with something like an Event Bus. http://square.github.io/otto/

Comment: Could you display progress in a notification instead? This would be much easier.

Comment: Thanks a lot svenoaks. able to stop service once all running task is done using stopself().Need to use stopSelf(int)(from thread) to ensure that your request to stop the service is always based on the most recent start request. That is, when you call stopSelf(int), you pass the ID of the start request (the startId delivered to onStartCommand()) to which your stop request corresponds. Then if the service received a new start request before you were able to call stopSelf(int), then the ID will not match and the service will not stop. http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html